# boost spirit headers deprecated

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I am following the quickstart guide for boost::spirit, and I get this compiler warning when I include  : "This header is deprecated. Please use: boost/spirit/include/classic_core.hpp" Should I be worried about this?

(quick start guide: http://spirit.sourceforge.net/distrib/spirit_1_8_5/libs/spirit/doc/quick_start.html , with full source of the program I am trying to compile here: http://spirit.sourceforge.net/distrib/spirit_1_8_5/libs/spirit/example/fundamental/number_list.cpp)

edit: Additionally, when I try to compile with the recommended classic_core.hpp and classic_push_back_actor.hpp headers, I get the following compiler errors:

```
test7.cpp: In function 'bool parse_numbers(const char*, __gnu_debug_def::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&)':
test7.cpp:18: error: 'real_p' was not declared in this scope
test7.cpp:18: error: 'push_back_a' was not declared in this scope
test7.cpp:23: error: 'space_p' was not declared in this scope
test7.cpp:23: error: 'parse' was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[EDIT:] The original answer is badly out of date; in particular the link is broken.  The current version of Boost (since 2012-02-24) is 1.49.0.

The warning mentioned is a result of `#include <boost/spirit.hpp>` which is a deprecated header; however old examples on the web use this form. To get started, try the [boost tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials.html). Once you see the correct includes and namespaces, most old examples can easily be converted.

[OLD ANSWER:]

You must be using boost 1.39 or later (via SVN). This presentation should help:

- http://www.boostcon.com/site-media/var/sphene/sphwiki/attachment/2009/05/07/SpiritV2.pdf

In short, there's a brand new way of doing thing and these are the namespaces to use:

- `boost::spirit:qi` (for the parser)
- `boost::spirit::karma` (for the generator lib)

The official release is 1.40 so probably by that time the doc will be updated.

EDIT: [the doc in the boost SVN repository](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) is being worked on and probably reflect the new architecture in a more faithful manner.

Answer (score 1):

When you're including the classic headers the parsers are in the boost::spirit::classic namespace.  Try:

> using namespace boost::spirit::classic;

Answer (score 0):

When a library indicates that a class/header/method/etc. is deprecated, it means that the maintainer of the library will most likely stop maintaining the functionality, and may remove it in the future.  I would recommend to switch to the suggested header sooner than later, so save yourself from headaches in the future.

The new header may have a slightly different way of handling the feature, so you may need to make some code changes.

(I don't know much about boost, this is just a general comment)